# RSpec: What are the alternatives to 'allow_any_instance_of'?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec

In [the documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) the Rspec Mocks maintainers

> ... discourage its use for a number of reasons...

The reasons listed seem to relate to the `expect` version of this functionality, but they make no distinction between the two.

I can see why the `expect` version is discouraged, but the `allow` version doesn't seem to share the problems listed.

It seems like using the `allow` version is the most expedient way to test certain types of behaviour.

**Example:**

I'm testing authorization of some routes. One approach is to fabricate a user in the DB, but that seems fairly heavy handed, I prefer to just create a mock object and return it during the authorize call. This example is a specific case of testing code that uses complex libraries, which are tested separately.

Given that it's discouraged, what are the better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation that you posted, the reason to not use `allow_any_instance_of` is that it is too heavy handed and can cover up potential code smells that you might miss. With that said, I still use it... they definitely aren't offering up an alternative, so if you need that functionality and have pondered other options or other ways to write your tests and decided against those, just use it.

Comment: I found the documentation lacking, which is why I asked the question. Particularly that it makes no distinction between the `allow` and `expect` variations, and also proposes no alternatives.

Comment: I believe the author of the documentation is discouraging both the `allow` and `expect` versions of these methods, although they used `expect` in their examples.

They provided an example using `Widget`, as in:

```
As a result there are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example, in expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice it isn't clear whether a specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)
```
Instead, try passing in the collaborator as a mock and making expectations on it, rather than any instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe there are any alternatives in Rspec, other than changing the way in which you write your tests, which is what they are proposing. Both `allow` and `expect` are very broad and can cover up other mistakes that you may have made.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `allow_any_instance_of` stubs a method on every instance of a class. This is dangerous in that you could accidentally be referencing the wrong instance of the object in your test, which could lead to the wrong result.

But, if that's reason enough for the RSpec team to recommend not using it, why did they include it? And, what's the alternative?

There are good reasons. But, before I get there, let me explain the alternative.

Consider this code:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    baz = Baz.new(1)
    baz.qux
  end
end

class Baz
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def qux
    @value
  end
end
```

Say I want to stub the `qux` method on the `baz` instance? I can do that with `allow_any_instance_of`. But, what if we need multiple instances of `Baz` inside the `Foo#bar` method?

```
class Foo
  def bar
    baz1 = Baz.new(1)
    baz2 = Baz.new(2)
    baz1.qux + baz2.qux
  end
end
```

Now, when we `allow_any_instance_of(Baz).to receive(:qux)`, we're allowing both instances to receive the message. Maybe that's okay for some use cases. But, a more testable design would pass the instances of `Baz` into the `bar` method or the `Foo#initialize` method. This technique is called dependency injection. It looks like this:

```
# constructor injection
class Foo
  def initialize(baz1, baz2)
    @baz1, @baz2 = baz1, baz2
  end

  def bar
    @baz1.qux + @baz2.qux
  end
end

# calling code
Foo.new(Baz.new(1), Baz.new(2)).bar
```

Now, your test can pass in actual `Baz` objects (if they're lightweight) or mock them individually (if they're costly) rather than using the crude club of `allow_any_instance_of`.

So, why wouldn't folks just always use dependency injection?

Well, it turns out that some frameworks make that impossible. Ruby on Rails, for example, hides the creation of controller objects from the developer. So, there's no opportunity to create an initializer and inject dependencies into the controller. Therefore, you must create any dependencies in the controller methods themselves, which leaves you with no other choice than to use `allow_any_instance_of`.

(Well, technically, you could also stub Baz.new to return an instance_double that stubs the qux method. But, now you're all up in the implementation, which makes refactoring that code much harder, because you'll break all your tests. Don't do that either.)

Finally, legacy code – code without tests – is often written without dependency injection. So, `allow_any_instance_of` allows you to put tests around the existing code before you begin refactoring to a more testable implementation.